# Difference in evaluation of expression when using long long int vs double in c++

Tags: c++, double

I'll refer to the below code to explain my question.

```
typedef long long int ll;

void func(){
    ll lli_a = 603828039791327040;
    ll lli_b = 121645100408832000;
    double d_b = (double)lli_b;
    cout << "a " << lli_b - d_b << endl; \\0
    cout << "b " << (lli_a - 4*lli_b) - (lli_a - 4*d_b) << endl; \\64
    cout << "c " << (lli_a - 4*lli_b) - (lli_a - (ll)4*d_b) << endl; \\64
    cout << "d " << (lli_a - 4*lli_b) - (lli_a - 4*(ll)d_b) << endl; \\0
    cout << "e " << 4*(ll)d_b - 4*d_b << endl; \\0
    cout << "f " << 4*(ll)d_b - (ll)4*d_b << endl; \\0
}
```

I'm unable to understand why statements b and c have evaluated to 64, while d has evaluated to 0, which happens to be the correct answer.

Both e and f evaluate to 0, so the difference is coming because of subtraction from `lli_a` I assume. I don't think there is any overflow issue as individual values for each term are coming correctly.

Comment: Two notes about the code: First of all don't create aliases like `ll`, that actually makes the code *harder* to read, understand and maintain; Secondly whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like `(ll)d_b`) in C++ you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: An IEEE-754 `double` has ~16 decimal digits of precision. Your constants have 19 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code to walk you through it, bottom line don't mix doubles with ints implicitly

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// typedef long long int ll; NO , use using and never use aliasing to safe a bit of typing. Aliases are there to introduce meaning not shortcuts

//using namespace std; // also NO

int main() 
{
    long long int lli_a = 603828039791327040;
    long long int lli_b = 121645100408832000;
    //double d_b = (double)lli_b;                     // No this is C++ don't use 'C' style casts
    double d_b = static_cast<double>(lli_b);

    assert(static_cast<long long int>(d_b) == lli_b); // you are in luck the double can represent your value exectly, NOT guaranteed

    std::cout << "a " << lli_b - d_b << "\n"; //  endl; \\0 don't use endl unless you have a good reason to flush

    long long int lli_b4 = 4 * lli_b;
    
    // use auto to show you this expression evaluates to a double!
    auto lli_d_b4 = (lli_a - static_cast<long long int>(4) * d_b); // d_b is double!!! what do you want to do here? Use it as a long long int then cast it first
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(lli_d_b4)>);

    auto result_c = lli_b4 - lli_d_b4;
    // result c is still a double!
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(result_c)>);
    std::cout << "c " << result_c << "\n";
    
    // long story short don't mix types implicitly and use "C++" style cast explicitly to get the results you want

    /*

    
        cout << "b " << (lli_a - 4 * lli_b) - (lli_a - 4 * d_b) << endl; \\64
        cout << "c " << (lli_a - 4 * lli_b) - (lli_a - (ll)4 * d_b) << endl; \\64
        cout << "d " << (lli_a - 4 * lli_b) - (lli_a - 4 * (ll)d_b) << endl; \\0
        cout << "e " << 4 * (ll)d_b - 4 * d_b << endl; \\0
        cout << "f " << 4 * (ll)d_b - (ll)4 * d_b << endl; \\0
        */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a floating point type. Floating point types have limited precision. They cannot represent all numbers - not even all rational numbers. Simply (on your system) 603828039791327040 is a number that cannot be represented by the `double` datatype. The closest value that is representable happens to be 64 away from the precise value.

You can (likely) get the expected result by using `long double` which (typically) can represent all values of `long long` - or you could avoid using floating point in the first place.